# PHPUnit runs only from the command line. Why?

Tags: command-line, phpunit

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
    {
        public function testCalculate()
        {
            $this->assertEquals(2, 1 + 1);
        }
    }
?>
```

When I open the PHP file in the browser, I get the following error:

Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found

However, if I use the command line it works fine:
phpunit [local_path_here]/testcase.php

Result:

```
.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 5.00Mb

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

Why is that? How can I make it to run it in the browser as well?

Comment: Why hasn't this been answered!? I want to know!

Answer (score 4):

You can integrate add-on for running unit tests via native web GUI:

https://github.com/NSinopoli/VisualPHPUnit

Answer (score 2):

You can't run unit tests in the browser. Maybe in the future: http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/638-PHPUnit-3.0.html#c4983

If you want to view the code coverage run

```
phpunit --coverage-html=coverage testcase.php
```

and then open the index.html file in the coverage directory.

Otherwise, you have to run your tests from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a different include path on the command line. Check to see whether you have a `php-cli.ini` file in addition to the normal `php.ini` file. The first one will be used when you run PHP from the command line. That's probably got a different `include_path` setting. It might include the PEAR directory, for example, if PHPUnit was installed via PEAR.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eclipse also to run phpunit.
follow the link below

http://pkp.sfu.ca/wiki/index.php/Configure_Eclipse_for_PHPUnit