# PHPUnit: How to run tests from browser?

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I know PHPUnit tests can be executed from the command line, but is there an easy way to run it from the browser. For example, I have:

```
class testsSuite extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite
{

    public function __construct ()
    {
        $this->setName('testsSuite');
        $this->addTestSuite('MyFirstTest');
    }

    public static function suite ()
    {
        return new self();
    }
}
```

And then I have:

```
class MyFirstTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    protected function setUp ()
    {        
        parent::setUp();
    }

    protected function tearDown ()
    {
        parent::tearDown();
    }

    public function __construct ()
    {

    }

    public function test__construct ()
    {

    }

    public function test__destruct () {

    }

    public function testCalculateCost ()
    {
        print 1; die();
    }

}
```

Is there a URL I can enter in my browser to execute this test? Something like:

```
http://localhost/tests/testsSuite/calculateCost
```

Or something similar

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHPUnit runs only from the command line. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064951/phpunit-runs-only-from-the-command-line-why)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution that works well:

```
<?php

define("PHPUNIT_COMPOSER_INSTALL","vendor/autoload.php");

require PHPUNIT_COMPOSER_INSTALL;

$query = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];

//$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] to $_SERVER['argv'];

$_SERVER['argv'] = explode("&",$query);

//PHPUnit use $_SERVER['argv'] for input value

PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main(false);

/*Use

command line "./vendor/bin/phpunit param1 param2 param..."

browser URI "localhost?param1&param2&param..."

*/
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/25123881)

Answer (score 4):

There is [VisualPHPUnit](https://github.com/NSinopoli/VisualPHPUnit).

At work we sometimes run from browser, using in its basic form a php-script containing:

```
$argv = array(
    '--configuration', 'phpunit.xml',
    './unit',
);
$_SERVER['argv'] = $argv;


PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main(false);
```

So you basically put all parameters you normally type on the commandline in an array, and set it in the $_SERVER-global. PHPUnit_TextUI_Cmmand::main(false); then runs your tests. The false-parameter makes sure no exit() is called.
In the PHPUnit.xml I configure to log to a JSON file, and the php-script reads that file to show the results (which it can do after the tests because no exit was called).

Note: this is very barebone, simplistic and crude.